# Ways to convert excel to html table while preserving excel cell formatting

Tags: python

I am looking for ways to convert excel table with a specified sheet name and cell range to static html using Python. I tried xlsx2html but the formatting is not being preserved.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to load the table to dataframe (use pandas.read_csv (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), they are great with csv) and the upload your data to the html page (drop it into iframe, or container)

Comment: Excel cell format in that case won't be retained I believe. Also, I have merged cells in my excel data which don't reflect well in dataframes.....

Comment: dataframe saves the formatting of csv (use pandas.read_csv (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). What it does not saves is the conditional formatting of your excel file. if it's the issue you should use another way.

Comment: Could you suggest me any other means to go about this?

Comment: @AdamZaft Could you please elaborate over the other ways? I am totally stuck with losing conditional formatting while exporting excel as html.